# Inequality sums of powers

Tags: inequality

Prove that $$(\sum a_i^2)^4 \geq n^2 \cdot (\sum a_i^4)(\sum a_i)$$ given $\prod a_i=1$. Is it even true? It kind of looks like Cauchy Schwarz but the wrong way round. How to use the product=1 maybe Power mean but the powers are the wrong way round. Jensen
s would be nice but how to get the 4th powers less than something??? Any help would be much appreciated... ($n \geq 3$???)

Comment: I think you should at least give your motivation in wanting to consider such a (in my opinion ugly) inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My motivation is that I am curious to find the best bound on k and q $(\sum a_i^{small})^k \geq (\sum a_i^{big})^q)$ because it would be useful in solving some inequalities i am working on. Most of them are $n \geq 3$ do you think there is a comparable contradictory case for that.

Comment: Well did you even try a **very similar** example for $n = 3$? You have a calculator, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

False. Let $n = 2$ and $(a_1,a_2) = (8/9,9/8)$. Then the inequality is false.

The question was modified after the above counter-example, but in any case it can be trivially extended for any $n > 1$ as follows:

Let $(a_1,a_2) = (1-ε,\frac{1}{1-ε})$ and $a_i = 1$ for any $i \in [3..n]$, and then compute the asymptotic expansion for the inequality as $ε \to 0$, which would show that the inequality is reversed for any $ε \in I$ for some open neighbourhood $I$ of $0$.